# Franck-Hertz experiment - the shape of the I/V relation graph

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

Why does the I/V graph of Frank-Hertz experiment looks like a spindle? I understand the reson of the periodic structure but don't understand why the maxim of the current goes with a gradually flat tendency whereas the minimum of the current goes with a gradually steep tendency.[image]
figure:http://mgh-images.s3.amazonaws.com/9781133712237/8672-4-46PEI1.png

Comment: I'm not confident enough to give a full answer, but the reason why the current increases at all with accelerating voltage is because it's space-charge limited: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_charge#Space-charge-limited_current. One of the complications is that the pressure is high enough to be heavily scattering. What I'm not sure about is why the peaks are levelling off.